# How to Select one of the same name values in one column via input type and then submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

What Im trying to do is put one name into a input type box and press submit, once submitted Id like it only to show all the same name rows and NOT all names in database? Can anyone help as I'm trying out or || in the PHP but only getting all results?

```
<form method="post" action="">
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<button onclick="refreshMap()">Refresh</button>
</form>

function refreshMap() {
var name = $('#name').val();
}

<script>      
$(function() {
$('#name').val(name);
});
</script>
```

PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE name IN ('John' || 'Gina')";

$result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result === FALSE) { 
        die(mysql_error()); 
    }

if(!empty($_POST['name']))

{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo $row['name'];

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

```
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);

if(!empty($name))
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE name LIKE '" .$name ."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result === FALSE) {
        die(mysql_error());
        exit(0);
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row['name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks tried that out but still get all results from table?

Comment: You need your results to be filtered based on what ? (that date column for the example ?)

Comment: Please update your post with the schema of your `register` database table.

Comment: I need to select Iver John or Gina to shown the date column for that name which is chosen, hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the correct syntax for the `IN` clause. (the values should be separated by commas) Check my update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99591/discussion-between-jonas-and-sparta).

Comment: Thanks so so much A++